# Access 2013 Web App - How to select the first record in a table using expression builder?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am using Access 2013 Web apps to build an application. I have one table containing a list of organisations, and another table containing comments about the organisations. One organisation can have many comments.

I am trying to write a query that will select the organisation and the first comment about that organisation from the comments table. However, this is proving quite difficult with the limited Web App functions (that is, I do not know how to select only the first comment - it is selecting all of the comments associated with the organisation). I have looked high and low how to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike. I believe this might be possible, however, we would first need to know by what means are you determining which comment is the "first". Do you have a date/time field associated with each of these comments in the Comments table or are you simply going off the AutoNumber field in the Comments table? If you can describe your table and field structure a bit more that would help us provide an answer.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. The organisations table has an `ID` and `OrgName` column. The comments table has an `ID`, `OrgID`, `comment`, and `date` column. I would like to get the comment with the most recent date for that organisation if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do this is build a query that joins in all the child records but in a SORTED order. Say like this:

[image]

Note how in above the sort order is by DESCENDING comment date. In your case you could sort by DESCENDING PK [ID] of the CHILD table. So you can sort by any column, and just sort descending on the column you want the most recent row. As noted, if you don't have a comments date column, then just sort by PK [id] of the CHILD table.

Once you have the above, then you can write a data macro that returns the FIRST row, which will thus be the most recent based on the last row.

So the data macro can look like this:
[image]

And in a form, your macro code to “fetch” the most recent comments and stuff results into a un-bound text box can look like this:

[image]